# Excel: How to analyze data in a table that contains multivalue cells

Tags: excel, multivalue

I am working in a science project right now about insects, and I have been logging information about the insects I have been finding along. Right now, I realize that it was a bad decision to register the name of all the insects that I been finding per each observation.
I am not allowed to provide to much information because it is confidential, but I am going to add a similar example of my case in the following table:

| # of sample | insect (family) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Dermestidae, Histeridae |
| 2 | Histeridae, Dichotumius |
| 3 | Histeriade |
| 4 | Dermestidae, Histeridae |
| 5 | Cleridae, Dichotumius |
| 485 | Histeriade |
| 486 | Dermestidae, Histeridae |
| 487 | Dermestidae, Cleridae |
| 488 | Histeriade |

Something like the above table. In my actual table, I have cells with 5 or 6 diferent insects. The thing is:

- How can I search for all the different values? I mean, I want to create a table that contains all the different values and how many of them are... Something like the following table:

| Insect (family) | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Cleridae | 54 |
| Histeridae | 154 |
| Dermestidae | 34 |

(There are at least 100 different insects and some of them just appear once, so it is impossible for me to search all the different names manually.

Furthermore, I was thinking about converting my table to a long structure. Something like the following;

Instead of this:

| # of sample | insect (family) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Dermestidae, Histeridae |
| 2 | Histeridae, Dichotumius |
| 3 | Histeriade |
| 4 | Dermestidae, Histeridae |
| 5 | Cleridae, Dichotumius |

I want this:

| # of sample | insect (family) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Dermestidae |
| 1 | Histeridae |
| 2 | Histeridae |
| 2 | Dichotumius |
| 3 | Histeriade |
| 4 | Dermestidae |
| 4 | Histeridae |
| 5 | Cleridae |
| 5 | Dichotumius |

I was thinking that this arrangement should be better than the one that I have now.
I hope someone can help me with this issue. Thanks so much.

I tried the above, but I did´t got it. That's the reasons I asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer 'How can I search for all the different values?', the below formula will create a unique list of the insect families (where the insect families are in range `B2:B100`)

```
=UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,B2:B100),"|",", ",TRUE))
```

You will then be able to use a `COUNTIF()` formula to find how many tests contain each family.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to accomplish is called ***unpivoting*** data. Power query is best for this case. If you want it to do by formula then can try the following formula-

```
=DROP(REDUCE(0,REDUCE(0,B2:B6,LAMBDA(a,x,VSTACK(a,CONCAT(CHOOSEROWS(A2:A6,ROW(x)-1)&"|")&TEXTSPLIT(x,,",")))),LAMBDA(p,q,VSTACK(p,TEXTSPLIT(q,"|")))),2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

*I am uncertain if you want just the unpivoted table, the Counts of each family, or something else, but I have shown the results at each of the last two steps in the query. You can use what you need.*

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//Change next line to reflect your actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Insects"]}[Content],

//set the data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"# of sample", Int64.Type}, {"insect (family)", type text}}),

//Split Insect Family column by the comma, into rows
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = 
        Table.ExpandListColumn(
            Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {{"insect (family)", 
                Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(
                    ",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), 
                "insect (family)"),

//Remove any leading and trailing spaces => your unpivoted table
    #"Trim Spaces" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter", {"insect (family)", each Text.Trim(_), type text}),

//To create your table with counts, merely Group by the insect (family) column and aggregate with Count
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Trim Spaces", {"insect (family)"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

***Source Data***
[image]

***Next to last step showing unpivoted table***
[image]

***Last Step***
[image]

Comment: Using Power Query will be the easiest and neat way to resolve. Hooray!!!